# How to connect this jquery code to this hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to connect this line of HTML (which activates a hover pop-up) code which is being used in a PHP file, to the following jquery code. I've gotten it to work for in a single hover instance, but I plan on having multiple hovers all across the page.

HTML Code:

```
<a class="que" href="http://www.google.com">okok</a> 
<div class="launch">test</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.launch").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})
    $("a.que").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).next('.launch').animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).sibling('div').stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 200);
        }
    )
});
```

Thanks a ton for any help... :)

Comment: do you want to add this hover to all `<a>` tags and its next `div`s?

Comment: No, I'm mainly aiming to only target certain ones. Basically I'm defining a keyword in the wordpress admin area. Based on that keyword it links to a certain page and displays defined data inside the hover. I'm currently just trying to get the hover to work in all situations, but for some reason it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your jQuery selector to match all elements you want to have that hover effect.  The jQuery selector is the part of the jQuery statement that tells you what items to, well, select.

```
$(selectorGoesHere).takeSomeAction;
```

The selector matches the same format you use for the CSS, so, for example, any element with `class="someClass"` will be selected in jQuery with `$(".someClass")`.  The jQuery selector can refer to multiple matching items simultaneously, so the jQuery statement used a moment ago would select *every element that has that class* and perform whatever action you chose.

If, for example, you wanted to use jQuery to set every `div` to have a red background, you would use:

```
$("div").css("background-color","#FF0000");
```

Broken down, that statement finds every `div` element (as specified by the selector), then applies the CSS style `background-color: #FF0000` to EVERY `div` in the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/hzm5p/1/ is an example of having multiple hover-over effects using your code.  Just follow that link for a sample how how your already written jQuery statements are applied to multiple HTML elements.

**EDIT:** Based on the code below, change your jQuery to match http://jsfiddle.net/hzm5p/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div.launch").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})

    jQuery("a.que").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(this).parent().next('.launch').animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        },
        function () {
            jQuery(this).parent().next('.launch').stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 200);
        }
    )
});​
```

Simply add `.parent()` to get the the containing `p` element, then take the `.next('.launch')` element.

**EDIT 2:** For jQuery in Wordpress, you need to include the following line somewhere in your `functions.php` file:

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
```

Also, it seems that the jQuery used by Wordpress is designed for "compatibility mode", which means the $ shortcut is by default unavailable.  You'll need to use `jQuery` in place of $, unless you use some of the workarounds mentioned in http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

**EDIT 3:** Test for jQuery loading with the following code:

```
if (jQuery) {  
    alert("jQuery loaded"); 
} else {
    alert("jQuery not loaded");
}
```

If it's loaded, then I don't know what to tell you.  If it isn't, you need to figure out why in Wordpress and get it loaded, or you'll need to re-write your code to use non-jQuery scripting.

Comment: I literally started programming about a week ago, so I'm still kinda new to this in terms of "needs explanations" haha...

Would you mind expanding on that a bit?

Comment: @saluce, if he is trying to show the div on hover and hide on blur then the fiddle isn't correct. here is a updated version http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/hzm5p/1/

Comment: @Joy good point; I was demonstrating the effect being available on all appropriate divs without worrying about the onblur effect =)

Comment: It does in terms of understanding, although I think my original problem is still there. For some reason the div just isn't displaying.

I can get it to run on a normal html document, but whenever I attempt the same thing in wordpress it breaks.

Basically the php code auto-generates the <a class="whatever" href="blah blah">

Here's how I have the php code setup... $expr_to[] = '$1<a class="que" href="'.$val.'">$2</a>$3' . '<div class="launch">test</div>';

Comment: I keep running into the problem that wordpress puts <p></p> tags around the <a href> and separates the <div> outside of that. Which I'm thinking is breaking the connection for the hover to properly work.

Comment: Post the code that is actually generated by Wordpress and we can help you get the right selector.

Comment: <div class="entry-content">
<p>
Duis a eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos.
<a class="que" href="http://www.google.com">testkeyword</a>
</p>
<div class="launch" style="display: block; opacity: 0;">test</div>
sodales ac, urna. Phasellus luctus venenatis magna. Vivamus eget lacus. Nunc tincidunt convallis tortor. Duis eros mi, dictum vel, fringilla sit amet, fermentum id, sem. Phasellus nunc enim, faucibus ut, laoreet in, consequat id, metus.
<p></p>
</div>

Comment: Here's the code with the update you said, **http://screencast.com/t/iCah827itvgP** Here's the actual output of what it looks like **http://screencast.com/t/MFpW4DvFpq** I'm honestly just clueless as to why this isn't work, I've tried a dozen variations in the .js file.

Comment: Is the hover actually working now? Are you trying to position it at the mouse? What exactly is not working right now?

Comment: The hover is on the page but it's there permanently. It just appears with the page load. Whenever you actually "hover" it doesn't do anything except have the hyperlink to google.com

Comment: Are you certain you added jQuery?  For reference, you need to go into your `functions.php` file and add the line `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");`.  Also, it appears you'll need to modify the code use the full jQuery name, not the `$` shortcut.  http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Just went ahead and changed it from $ to jQuery, as well as loaded the jQuery library via php inside the plugin's code (rather than the functions file). It's loading correctly, but the hover is still not working. http://screencast.com/t/MFpW4DvFpq That's still the problem I'm having where the hover is still not working, but appears upon page load. For testing purposes to see if it was even detecting the hover event, I added a simple alert("testing"); before the initial hover event and it's apparently not detecting anything. Honestly this has me completely stumped... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use class `que` to all `<a>` tags and `launch` class to all `div`s next to that `<a>` tags.